# Animating a div on hover css - possible loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Wordpress site using Bootstrap framework

```css
.test {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 50%;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: -5em;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.linkage:hover + .test {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 indx-img" style="background-image:url('...');">
  
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="linkage">Link</a>
    
     <div class="test"> Test </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now my site has the div 'test' show up (opacity 1) vertically/horiz centred when the the link 'linkage' is hovered on (linkage is 100% height and width of the container).

I want to animate the 'test' div as it fades in on hover. I was thinking using scale (on hover the div scales down to its original size then scales up on fade out) or something. Unless anyone has a cooler idea

Comment: Is that what you want (minimal example)? https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/d33maa33/

Comment: that's basically exactly what I have going right now. I want to add a scale factor, it's being applied to a div with a background image

Comment: Sorry, I had not looked at the fiddle (and your comment) before answering but what is wrong with it? I see the scale happening there. Do you mean you want the factor to be controlled dynamically (or) you want it changed in a non linear way?

Comment: I don't have any scale transitions it it yet, thats what I want though. '.test' fades in (opacity 0 - 1) but I want it to animate in with scale, like grow/shrink on hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for something like the below snippet (a transition and not animation). On `hover` of the link, the `.test` is being scaled up two times its original size both along X and Y axes and on mouse out it is brought back to its normal size.

```css
.test {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;  /* added as I think this was missed in your code */
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  margin-left: -5em;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500);  /* added for image */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;  /* modified to transition all property changes */

  /* added to scale up the div with the center as the origin */
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleX(2) scaleY(2);
}
.linkage:hover + .test {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);  /* bring back to normal state */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 indx-img" style="background-image:url('...');"> 
    <a href="#" class="linkage">Link</a>
    <div class="test">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternately, you could use matrix transforms also. Equivalent of `translateY(-50%) scaleX(2) scaleY(2)` would be `matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 0, -101)` and that of `translateY(-50%) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)` would be `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, -101)`.

Comment: That's more like it! I'll work it into my code thank you

Comment: Unfortunately I spoke to soon, your snippet seems to do what I want, but it doesn't work on my code. The opacity change still works, but the scale isn't affected

Comment: @user3550879: Can you please show a demo of your full code? Also, make sure you have included all the prefixes (I have used prefix free JS library in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Well this will never be true:

```
.linkage:hover + .test {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

as linkage (hovered or not) is not a sibling of test.

.test is absolutely positioned, but has no parent element that is not static.  Did you want to to be absolute to the body?  You use left/margin to horizontally center, and it looks like you are trying to use translateY to vertically center, but you never specify top.  Perhaps consolidating to one method?

```
top:50%; left:50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: I apologize, I fixed my code snippet to correct that, I copied it in the wrong place. The snippet is inside an 'article' which has no defined height (it's height is created with 'padding: 15% 0; applied to .index-img'